# mysql on delete cascade do not work

Tags: mysql, uuid, cascade

I'm trying to use ON CASCADE DELETE in mysql db but I can't make it work.
Here is my code:

```
CREATE TABLE sometable
(
testId CHAR(43),
blocked BOOL,
PRIMARY KEY(testId)
 );

CREATE TABLE p
( 
testId CHAR(43),
phrase text,
source text,
FOREIGN KEY (testId) REFERENCES sometable (testId) on delete cascade
);

CREATE TRIGGER sometable_insert BEFORE INSERT ON `sometable` FOR EACH ROW SET NEW.`testId` =UUID();
```

I then perform an insert into sometable, which will generate a UUID.
I take this UUID and insert it to table p. 
    insert into p(testId, phrase, source) values('07616f60-424f-11df-871a-b98e9', 'fun', 'test');

When doing a delete on the row in sometable nothing happens in table p.
What have i missed or what I'm i doing wrong

Comment: Maybe you have to define an index on the testId column in the p table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, found the solution. I had to specify the type to innodb like this:

```
CREATE TABLE sometable
(
testId CHAR(43),
blocked BOOL,
PRIMARY KEY(testId)
) type=innodb;
```

Thank you for the comments

// Jakob